# Node.js sequelize 3 models with 1 pivot

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create my models and relationships for a Node.js application with a MySQL database. My models are the following:

**User, Area, Level**

**I want the level a user has on a specific area**. So the relations should be something like this. So all of them are in a many-to-many relationship with each other.

User.hasMany(Area)

User.hasMany(Level)

Area.hasMany(Level)

Area.hasMany(User)

Level.hasMany(User)

Level.hasMany(Area)

Do want to connect them throught one pivot table i.e. area_employee_levels that will include **user_id, area_id, level_id**. Is there any way to do this with sequelize? And then how to get select the user with all the relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read this part of the documentation for [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships).
It will help you on you issue

Comment: There is no documentation with pivot for 3 tables. I also haven't seen any valid implementation while searching.